# MVC4: Switching from form to window authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

i tryed googoling for a whole afternoon yesterday but maybe I'm not able to search fine and i've not found a solution!

I've an MVC4 Application working well in Forms Authentication, but now the company request is to switch the authentication in windows Authentication.

I tried to simply change the web config and set it to Windows Authentication, but when i start the debug, the user is empty (User.Identity.Name = "").

So I tried to create, by the VS templates, a new intranet webapp to see if it works fine, and it does. I compared the web config and nothing is missing but I cannot understand how the application get the user, since here I found the User.Identity.Name data correct.

So I'm missing something or I just need to add some code?
Thanks for help.

-EDIT: I try to put a session-start check, but User.Identity is still empty and not authenticated. Cannot understand why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**:Open Web.config file and make following modifications:

```
<!—
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
-->

<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

**Step 2**:By default MVC apps uses Form Authentication and Simple Membership, so you need to make it ‘false’ in order to run Windows Authentication.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

  <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>

</appSettings>
```

**Step 3**:Select project name in solution explorer and then in the property explorer, click to enable the Windows Authentication.

**Step 4**:In the property explorer you can disable the Anonymous Authentication if you want your complete website for authenticated users on development server.

[Reference](http://www.itorian.com/2013/05/windows-authentication-in-mvc4-with-iis.html)

Comment: Changing "enableSimpleMembership" to False did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please verify this configuration for windows authentication

```
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="yourdomain\someotheruser" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

Comment: If I put this in web.config i am asked for User and password. I tried many times but i get the unauthorized page. So I think my site dosen't get the user. Notice: on the MVC example APP IE doesn't ask me for the USER/Password but my user is auto-recognized.

Comment: yes, you must enter correct DomainName/UserName and password (The one which you use to login into your machine). For IE, it has default setting "Automatic logon only in Intranet zone". To verify/change that settings go to IE > Tools > Internet Options > Security TAB > Custom Level > Scroll it to the end and look for User Authentication options.